# MYSQL select query including all if not specified

Tags: mysql, sql

In MYSQL, how would I create a select query to show all if the user has not entered anything.

For instance, I have an option where the user can enter a name, in a text box. However if no name is entered, it will return all results.

Example:

`select * from names where name=$name`

name is the variable the user enters.. however if the user does not enter name, it returns all records.

I have implemented this functionality before, I just cant remember how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
select * from names where @parameter IS NULL OR name = @parameter
```

where `@parameter` is a variable

Comment: this doe snot work.. as it looks for fields with anme as NULL